Mapping SQLAlchemy core tables with Domain models written by dataclasses
My goal is to associate User objects with their respective Language objects and query these relationships correctly. However, I'm encountering issues when trying to set a Language instance directly in the User instance.
Here's a simplified version of my code setup:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional
import logging as logger

from sqlalchemy import (
    Table, MetaData, Column, BIGINT, String, ForeignKey, func, select
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, registry, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine


DATABASE_URL = "sqlite+aiosqlite:///:memory:"
engine = create_async_engine(
    DATABASE_URL,
    # echo=True
)
AsyncSessionLocal = sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)


mapper_registry = registry()

metadata = MetaData()


# domain layer ---------------------------------------------------------------
@dataclass
class Language(object):
    code: str
    title: str

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Language {self.code} {self.title}>"


@dataclass
class User(object):
    id: int
    username: Optional[str]
    first_name: str
    last_name: Optional[str]
    ui_language_code: Language

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name or ''}"

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


# infrastructure layer ------------------------------------------------------

language_table = Table(
    "languages",
    metadata,
    Column("code", String(10), primary_key=True, unique=True),
    Column("title", String),
)


user_table = Table(
    "users",
    metadata,
    Column("id", BIGINT, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
    Column("username", String(32), unique=True),
    Column("first_name", String(64)),
    Column("last_name", String(64), default="", server_default=""),
    Column("ui_language_code", String, ForeignKey("languages.code", ondelete="CASCADE")),
)


def configure_mappers() -> None:
    """
    Configures mappers for the domain models here.
    """
    logger.info("Configuring mappers")

    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
        User,
        user_table,
        properties={
            'ui_language_code': user_table.c.ui_language_code,
            'ui_language': relationship(Language, foreign_keys=[user_table.c.ui_language_code]),
        }
    )

    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
        Language,
        language_table,
    )


configure_mappers()

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


async def create_tables():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(metadata.create_all)


async def count_objects(session: AsyncSession, domain: type[Language] | type[User]) -> int:
    stmt = select(func.count()).select_from(domain)
    result = await session.execute(stmt)
    objects = result.scalar()
    return objects


async def main():
    await create_tables()
    english_language_domain = Language(code="en", title="English")

    new_user = User(
        id=1,
        username="test",
        first_name="John",
        last_name="Doe",
        ui_language_code=english_language_domain.code,   # <----- Works only when I pass str,
        # ui_language_code=english_language_domain,      # <----- and doesn't work when I pass Language object
    )

    async with AsyncSessionLocal() as session:
        session.add(english_language_domain)
        session.add(new_user)
        await session.commit()

        logger.info("Counting languages")
        count = await count_objects(session, domain=Language)
        assert count == 1, "Language count is not 1"
        logger.info(f"Language count is {count}")

        logger.info("Counting users")
        count = await count_objects(session, domain=User)
        assert count == 1, "User count is not 1"
        logger.info(f"User count is {count}")

        # I would like to see the Language instance composed in the User instance
        assert new_user.ui_language_code == "en"
        assert isinstance(new_user.ui_language_code, Language), f"ui_language_code is not an instance of Language, it is type of {type(new_user.ui_language_code)}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import asyncio
    asyncio.run(main())


I'm trying to set a Language instance directly to ui_language_code in a User instance, but it only works when I pass the code attribute of the Language instance (a string) instead of the Language instance itself. I want to be able to work with the object directly and have SQLAlchemy handle the foreign key relationship behind the scenes.
How can I modify my mapping or insertion logic so that I can assign a Language object to ui_language_code and other similar fields in the User class, and have SQLAlchemy correctly handle these relationships?
Additionally, I would like to ensure that when querying User instances, I can access associated Language instances through properties like ui_language_code.
Any guidance or examples on how to properly set up these relationships and queries with SQLAlchemy would be appreciated.

Have you seen this?

@GordThompson I've found a good example, thanks for sharing.
Example https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/dataclasses.html#mapping-pre-existing-dataclasses-using-imperative-mapping
